# [affdex-sdk]encountered exception bad alloc

Tags: c++, affdex-sdk

I tried to run the affdex/cpp-sdk-samples downloaded from github. And I have encountered an exception.
After running the fllowing sentences:

`frameDetector->setClassifierPath(DATA_FOLDER);`

an error occured:

> Encountered an exception bad allocation

And VS2015 showes:

> 0x00007FF884FD9E08 处(位于 opencv-webcam-demo.exe 中)引发的异常: Microsoft C++ 异常: std::bad_alloc，位于内存位置 0x0000006ED96FF7E0 处。
>
> 0x00007FF884FD9E08 处(位于 opencv-webcam-demo.exe 中)引发的异常: Microsoft C++ 异常: std::bad_alloc，位于内存位置 0x0000006ED96FD280 处。
>
> 0x00007FF884FD9E08 处(位于 opencv-webcam-demo.exe 中)引发的异常: Microsoft C++ 异常: [rethrow]，位于内存位置 0x0000000000000000 处。
>
> 0x00007FF884FD9E08 处(位于 opencv-webcam-demo.exe 中)引发的异常: Microsoft C++ 异常: std::bad_alloc，位于内存位置 0x0000006ED96FD280 处。

My enviroment is windows 10 and visual studio 2015. I think i have configured the env right.
And I used

`-d D:\\data`

to specify the data folder.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The data directory is shipped with the tarball. The directory consists of classifier data files required by affdex-native.dll during runtime. Depending on the x64 or x86 executable that you have downloaded the data directory will be located at

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Affectiva\AffdexSDK\data

OR

> C:\Program Files\Affectiva\AffdexSDK\data

Comment: `affdex::path DATA_FOLDER(L"C:\\Program Files\\Affectiva\\AffdexSDK\\data");`
I did this, then it still told me that the path must be non-null. I am sure the folder is there and contains files. I wondered the problem maybe caused by VS version because I used vs2015.

Comment: what is the sdk version you are using?

Comment: X64. I downloaded this, AffdexSDK-3.4.1-575-win64.exe, from the develop portal.